# Can't get multiprocessing to work with my class instances in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

Basically I want to make few instances of the same object and execute them separately at the same time. Example code for this:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, username_, password_):
        self.username = username_
        self.password = password_
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

    def login(self):
        # Go to students page
        self.driver.get('https://www.students.com/')
        time.sleep(2)

        # Enter username in login form
        enter_username = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
        enter_username.send_keys(self.username)
        # Enter password in login form
        enter_password = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
        enter_password.send_keys(self.password)

        # Wait to send the form
        time.sleep(2)

        # Click Log In button
        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Iniciar sesión')]")[0].click()

        # Wait for the form to be sent
        time.sleep(5)
        self.start_working()
        # This functions is and endless loop that simulates work

if __name__ == '__main__':
            load_dotenv()

            query = "SELECT username, password FROM students"
            cursor.execute(query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()

            print("Total number of accounts botting up ", cursor.rowcount)

            object_list = list()
            for username, password in records:
                obj = Student(username, password)
                object_list.append(obj)

            instance_list = list()
            for x in object_list:
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=x.login)
                p.start()
                instace_list.append(p)

            for x in instance_list:
                x.join()
```

By now, I've gotten all of them to create the instance of the class, but I haven't been able to execute the login method for each instance.

I'm getting this error in the terminal:

```
 (student-bot) C:\python\student-bot>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alberto\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "c:\users\alberto\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado
[13852:1860:0427/193022.541:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(162)] [19:30:22.541] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1055 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `target=x.login`, not `x.login()`. Otherwise you would be calling whatever `target.login()` returns, which may not even be callable. The one "executing" process may actually just be the main thread and is a result that you have coded `x.login()`, but in fact none of the sub-processes are working. It would have been helpful to show error messages. Also make sure that the above code is within a block that begins:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

For example:

```
import multiprocessing

class Foo:
    def bar(self, i):
        print(i, flush=True)

f = Foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instace_list = list()
    for i in range(3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f.bar, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        instace_list.append(p)

    for x in instace_list:
        x.join()
```

Prints:

```
0
1
2
```

**Update**

Ideally your file should be structured thus:

```
import blah, blah, blah;

class Student: # or perhaps this is imported above
    # definition of this class

def foo():
    # definition of foo

def bar():
    #d definition of bar

def query_database():
        load_dotenv()
        # obtain connection and cursor (code not shown)
        query = "SELECT username, password FROM students"
        cursor.execute(query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()

        print("Total number of accounts botting up ", cursor.rowcount)

        object_list = list()
        for username, password in records:
            obj = Student(username, password)
            object_list.append(obj)

        return object_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
        object_list = query_database() # get Student list
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
            instance_list = list()
            for x in object_list:
                result = pool.apply_async(x.login)
                instance_list.append(result)

            for result in instance_list:
                result.get() # return value from login, which is None
```

**Update 2**

Since the `login` method does not appear to be a cpu-bound process, you might consider using threading. This code doesn't have to be within a `__main__` block (although it is perfectly correct to do so):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

object_list = query_database() # get Student list
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    instance_list = list()
    for x in object_list:
        future = executor.submit(x.login)
        instance_list.append(future)

    for future in instance_list:
        future.get() # return value from login, which is None
```

Comment: I edit the piece of code to show more details, I will try your answer and give feedback, I'm new to this stuff in Python and it's almost driving me insane

Comment: I modified the code in the post, and now every objects get created correctly, but I'm getting this error now, after all students have botted up, I haven't got them to execute the login function yet.

Comment: I would have to see what the `login` function is doing and perhaps the **rest of the code**. You must realize that for every sub-process created, the whole source file is executed again from top to bottom except for the code that is in the __main__ block (that's why the code that creates the sub-processes goes there). So ideally, the file should only consist of functions that are really not executed until you call them and class definitions. And then you should have one function that you can call in the __main__ block to query the database to get the required rows. I will update my answer.

Comment: Well I must say that I don't know what is causing that particular error. I have updated my code again to use a multiprocessing pool set to a max of 8 sub-processes. As your code now stands, if you have 5000 students, you will try to create 5000 processes. I am not saying that is causing the problem (it might be). But there is never any point in having more processes than the number of CPUs on your computer. My computer has 8, so I sent the number to 8. Your task is not particularly CPU bound, so you might instead try to use threading instead of multiprocessing.

Comment: I answered your original question as to why your weren't able to create the processes and successfully call the login method and presented a demo program that works correctly. Why the login method fails is something that is peculiar to that method. Perhaps something it is doing is incompatible with multiple instances running concurrently. But that I believe should be the subject of a new question you post tags that specifically state the tools you are using, e.g. the `chromdriver.exe` , and the environment in which you are running, i.e. Windows and get the help of people who know those things.

Comment: Yes, your solution works perfectly, I applied to my code and it worked, it seems that  running the chromedriver.exe must be making some conflicts, I will try to get it done, and will come back in a few days if I haven't. Thank you guys! Maybe I'll try to use threading too, I'll give it a shot and come back. Thank you both!

Comment: You can ACCEPT the answer. This was option number 2.